# FSharp embedded API add variables

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-compiler-services

Using the [Fsharp.Compiler.Serice Interactive API](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/interactive.html) I'd like to set variables to my FsiEvaluationSession object. Is this possible? Or is there another way to embed f# into an application for embedded-scripting purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this, but there is a lovely workaround:

```
// Define a mutable variable with default value
fsiSession.EvalInteraction "let mutable myVar = Unchecked.defaultof<int>"

// Create a function that sets the value of the variable
let f = evalExpressionTyped<int -> unit> "fun x -> myVar <- x"  

// Run the function to set the value of `myVar` to whatever we want
f 42

// As a bonus, use variable shadowing to make it immutable
fsiSession.EvalInteraction "let myVar = myVar"
```

This uses the `evalExpressionTyped` helper from the FCS documentation.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to pass a non-primitive-type host-object into the script. Though If nothing better "pops-up", I'll go ahead and accept this answer since it technically answers the stated-question. Idea: I could always use a string and allow my object to load it's state from the string. Though then it'll be a different object reference.

Comment: Great workaround. But what is the deep reason why we cannot do it directly ?

Comment: @RoyalPotato You can use this to provide non-primitive types too. You just need to first evaluate `#r` interaction to load the assembly from which the type is coming.

Comment: @FZed I think there is no reason why the FCS API would not be able to expose this functionality. Feel free to open an issue - or even help us add it!

Comment: Ah yes, but the trouble is that I can't very well pass an _object reference_ shared by my "base-code" not just a _type_ in. Could singleton it or static-ify I guess.

Comment: I think you can pass object references there too - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You know what? You're right. Sorry, it was too late for me to think previously. ;)